# how to display images from public folder in laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

i am trying to display an image which is located in **storage/app/uploads**. I already run the "**php artisan storage:link**" command and it was a success but its still not showing. When i also inspect the code in the browser the image is there together with the path. 'Upload' is linked to the image path.

```
    @foreach($user->posts as $post)
    <div class="col-4">
        <img class="w-100" src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}">
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: the helper asset was exactly build for this case {{ asset('img/' . $post->image) }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this solution:**

use asset(), its get files from public folder

```
@foreach($user->posts as $post)
    <div class="col-4">
        <img class="w-100" src="{{ asset('images/' . $post->image) }}">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: tried using asset() and nothing is happening but the path is the correct one. I think it has to do with restrictions even though i linked the folders

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options either use the direct url or asset method--

```
@foreach($user->posts as $post)
    <div class="col-4">
        <img class="w-100" src="{{ asset(yourpath) }}">
    </div>
    @endforeach

OR

@foreach($user->posts as $post)
    <div class="col-4">
        <img class="w-100" src="{{ url(yourpath) }}">
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

your path would be after the storage directory in public directory.